# Remove margins from the Toolbar and color

Tags: android, android-layout, include, toolbar

I have a custom ToolBar that I've included in the Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <include
                    layout="@layout/toolbar"
                    layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-45dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/splash">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="155dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
            android:text="@string/alma"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
            android:text="@string/unibo"
            android:textColor="@color/unibo"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is a view from AVD:
[MainActivity with custom Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iftzv.png)

Finally Toolbar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bar_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searching_bar"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_finder"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7.5dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_find"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"></LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/setting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7.5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_setting"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"></LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7.5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_user"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"></LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7.5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_message"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"></LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7.5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I move my custom Layout and remove the blue color from the background?

Comment: do you want to remove custom layout?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to the Toolbar as the android widget comes with a default padding:
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"

Also, you have to edit the MyMaterialTheme style in your styles.xml file -This theme is applied to your AppBar which is setting the background.

Answer (score 0):

**How can I move my custom Layout?**

Update your `Toolbar` with adding below `attributes`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp" 
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">

    .................
    ..........................
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**How can I remove the blue color from the background?**

You can change `Toolbar` background `color` by using attribute `android:background`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    ................
    .....................
    android:background="#ff0000"> <!--Here #ff0000 is for RED color-->
```

**OR**, you can do this by changing the value of `colorPrimary` in your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

Hope this will help~